# How to make a tag unclickable after one click with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code. I just need to make a tag un-clickable after the first click.

```
<li>
   <a class="active orig-a" href="/webizdropship/adminhtml_createorder/?sku=<?php echo base64_encode(urlencode($this->getProduct()->getSku())); ?>&qty=1">
   <?php echo $this->__('Add to cart') ?>
   </a>
</li>
```

I tried the code below:

```
jQuery('orig-a').click(false)
```

The `disabled` property also didn't work. jQuery `one` didn't help. When I'm clicking on `a` tag, its button, it has `href` and it sends results as much as I click on this tag. Page is loading for a long time.

If I click on it, server responds for about 30 seconds and with jQuery I need to don't send on click again on that address, otherwise it adds quantity as much as I click on it.

Comment: use the `.one` event listener. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Use [`one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one)

Comment: I saw your update, `one()` works fine. Also note that `orig-a` is not a valid selector so you will need to fix that as well. If it's a class or id, make sure you include the relevant prefix. If it's still not working for you, please edit the question to include a useful example of the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can set off click for a tag or use one click

```
$("#test").click(function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  $(this).off('click');
})
```

Use one click

```
 $( "#onetest" ).one( "click", function( event ) {
       console.log('one clicked');
    });
```

```js
$("#test").click(function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  $(this).off('click');
})

$( "#onetest" ).one( "click", function( event ) {
   console.log('one clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="test">Test disable</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="onetest">Test One Click</a>
```

Comment: Your code is not preventing the browser from following the link. Replace `#` with `javascript:alert('tada')` and you will see the alert everytime you click on the link. Need to use `event.preventDefault()` as well.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com I tried to add javascript:alert('tada') to href, but second click it did not alert anything? Can you make a sample?

Comment: See [your code in action](https://jsfiddle.net/mx6nyvca/) where alerts are shown every time you click on the link.

Comment: where can i put preventDefault, i put it in code but click again it still alert? https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/vsr7ja6h/4/

Comment: I was wrong about `preventDefault()`, I read the question again and `preventDefault()` won't help here. Another mechanism should be used depending on how the OP handles click event.